# Replace string globally using veriable

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I'm trying to replace string globally using the variable, but getting an unexpected replacement while replacing it. I've searched the same issue but didn't get any solutions so I'm posting it here. Maybe you guys will lead me where I'm doing a mistake.

Here is the case:

1. I have an `HTML` mail body and a list of links that I've extracted from the mail body and stored it as an array.
2. I'm trying to iterate the links array and try to find the match from the mail body.
3. And when I'm using the `replace()` method to replace the link by adding some prefix.

Looks pretty straight forward, right?

Here is the issue I'm getting while replacing the links.

There are some repeated links I've. While trying to replace them with the prefix, it is getting replace 2 times.

for e.x.

```
prefix = 'http://this.prefix?redirect_uri='
link = 'http://google.com'

// Expected Output
http://this.prefix?redirect_uri=http://google.com

// Getting Output
http://this.prefix?redirect_uri=http://this.prefix?redirect_uri=http://google.com
```

You can see the prefix is getting repeated.

I'm sharing my actual code, So, it will be more helpful to you guys to understand what I mean to say.

```js
let mailBody = `
<div dir="auto">
  <a href="https://aabc.pagerduty.com/incidents">aabc.pagerduty.com</a>
  <a href="https://aabc.pagerduty.com/incidents/P9X3024">[FIRING:1] TooManyContainerRestarts (http 10.0.95.123:8080 kube-state-metrics newton newton/prometheus-operator-prometheus prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics infra critical) </a></p>
  <a href="https://aabc.pagerduty.com/incidents/P9X3024">View Incident</a>
  <p>URGENCY </p>
</div>
`;

const links = [
  'https://aabc.pagerduty.com/incidents',
  'https://aabc.pagerduty.com/incidents/P9X3024'
]

const processTrackingLinks = (linkArray, mailBody) => {
  const prefix = 'https://test.io?redirect_uri=';
  // const mapping = [];
  for (let i=0; i < linkArray.length; i++){
    const replacer = new RegExp(linkArray[i], 'g')
    mailBody = mailBody.replace(replacer, prefix + linkArray[i]);
  }

  return mailBody;
};

mailBody = processTrackingLinks(links, mailBody);

console.log(mailBody);
```

If you have any idea why it is happening,
Am I doing something wrong or it is an issue
just let me know.

Any resolution will be appreciated. :)

Comment: The `incidents/` links matches two search terms, so it'll get replaced twice. A quick fix is to insert the opening `"` into the links array and the prefix, then use `prefix + links[i].substring(1)` as replacement; that way it'll only match once: https://jsfiddle.net/14pgz2mf/

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't thought that the second link is becoming the substring of the first match, and that is the only reason this is getting massed up. You can write your thought on the answer section, I'll add it as a  correct answer.

Comment: A more robust solution would be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qgsb3moe/

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach. You don't need the `links` array anymore.

```
const process = mailBody => {
    return mailBody.replace(/href="/g, `href="http://test.io?redirect_uri=`)
}
```

Comment: Your approach is perfect, but we has a logic to collect the link from the `href`, that's why we have an array of links. So, it won't be that kind of replace. But I appreciate your efforts. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the links array you are using. Double replacement is due to the fact that "https://abc.pagerduty.com/incidents" is a substring of "https://abc.pagerduty.com/incidents/".

Use the following array instead:

```js
let links = [
  'https://abc.pagerduty.com/incidentsgoogle',
  'https://abc.pagerduty.com/incidents/',
  'https://abc.facebook.com'
];
```

As seen already, this approach would fail for strings with substring present in the links array.

To avoid such issues, change the process function to:

```js
const process = (links, mailBody) => {
  let prefix = 'http://test.io?redirect_uri='
  return mailBody.replace(/( href=["'])/g, "$1" + prefix);
};
```

Comment: Appreciated, But I just need to add more character in the actual replace text. 
adding Double quote has fixed the issue.